Given vector spaces $V$ generate all subspaces of $V \times V$ using subspaces of $V$
Given a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over a finite field, are there any nice way to generate all subspaces of $V \times V$ in terms of subspaces of $V$? So given a subspace $U$ of $V \times V$ I want to somehow rewrite it using subspaces of $V$. For example given subspaces $U_1,U_2$ of $V$, $U_1 \times U_2$ is a subspace of $V \times V $. But there are also other subspaces of $V\times V$ and I want to somehow characterize them in terms of subspaces of $V$.

I think the best you can do is a kind of "Goursat's Lemma" for vector spaces; think about the subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (lines throught the origin, the origin, the whole thing) compared to subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$ (the origin, the whole thing).

What do you mean by "finite vector space"?  Do you mean a "finite dimensional vector space over an infinite field like $\mathbb R$" or do you mean "a vector space with only finitely many elements, that is to say, a finite dimensional vector space over a finite field"?  In either case, if the base field is $\mathbb F$, just consider $\mathbb F^2$.  There aren't many subspaces of the one dimensional base, but there can be many subspaces of the two dimensional space.

hey, i mean finite dimensional vector space yes, but over a finite field. corrected it now.

Your phrasing is poor. "over a finite field $V$" suggests that $V$ is the field. Better: "a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over a finite field."

In general, not every subspace of $V\times V$ is of the form $W_1\times W_2$ for subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$ of $V$. Indeed, we can see this already in $\mathbb{R}^2$, where the only subspaces of this form are $\{(0,0)\}$, the $x$-axis, the $y$-axis, and all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, whereas we have any line through the origin determining a one-dimensional subspace.
(Even over finite fields this occurs: over $\mathbb{F}_2$, the diagonal subspace $\{(0,0), (1,1)\}$ in $\mathbb{F}_2\times\mathbb{F}_2$ is not of the form $W_1\times W_2$ with $W_1,W_2$ subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_2$.)
But you do have the equivalent of Goursat's Lemma.
If $V_1$ and $V_2$ are vector spaces (over the same field), $W_i$ and $Z_i$ subspaces of $V_i$ with $Z_i\leq W_i$, and $T\colon (W_1/Z_1)\to (W_2/Z_2)$ is a linear isomorphism, then we can define a subspace of $V_1\times V_2$ determined by $T$, the "graph of $T$":
$$ W_T = \{(x,y)\in W_1\times W_2\mid T(x+Z_1) = y+Z_2\}.$$
It is straightforward to verify that this is indeed a subspace of $V_1\times V_2$.
Goursat's Lemma tells you that all subspaces of $V_1\times V_2$ arise this way:
Theorem (Goursat's Lemma). Let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be vector spaces over the same field, and let $W\leq V_1\times V_2$. Then there exist subspaces $Z_i,W_i$ of $V_i$, $Z_i\leq W_i$, and a linear isomorphism $T\colon (W_1/Z_1)\to (W_2/Z_2)$ such that $W=W_T$.
Proof. Let
$$\begin{align*}
W_1 &= \{x\in V_1\mid \text{there exists }y\in V_2\text{ such that }(x,y)\in W\}\\
W_2 &= \{y\in V_2\mid \text{there exists }x\in V_1\text{ such that }(x,y)\in W\}.
\end{align*}$$
Now let $Z_1=\{x\in W_1\mid (x,\mathbf{0})\in W\}$ and $Z_2=\{y\in W_2\mid (\mathbf{0},y)\in W\}$.
Define $T\colon (W_1/Z_1)\to (W_2/Z_2)$ as follows: given $x\in W_1$, there exists $y\in W_2$ such that $(x,y)\in W$. Define $T(x+Z_1) = y+Z_2$.
First, this is well-defined: if $(x,y)$ and $(x,y')\in W$, then $(x,y)-(x,y') = (\mathbf{0},y-y')\in W$, hence $y-y'\in Z_2$. Therefore, $y+Z_2 = y'+Z_2$, so the value of $T(x+Z_1)$ does not depend on the pair we pick with first coordinate equal to $x$. And if $x+Z_1=x'+Z_1$, then $x-x'\in Z_1$, so $(x-x',0)\in W$ Therefore, if $(x',y)\in W$, then $(x-x',0)+(x',y) = (x,y)\in W$, so the image of $x+Z_1$ is the same as the image of $x'+Z_1$.
Second, this is linear. If $x,x'\in W_1$, then let $y,y'\in W_2$ such that $(x,y),(x',y')\in W$. Then $(x,y)+\alpha(x',y') = (x+\alpha x',y+\alpha y')\in W$, so $T(x+\alpha x'+Z_1) = y+\alpha y'+Z_2$. Thus,
$$T(x+\alpha x'+Z_1) = y+\alpha y'+Z_2 = y+Z_2 + \alpha(y'+Z_2) = T(x+Z_1) + \alpha T(x'+Z_1).$$
Third, $T$ is one-to-one: if $T(x+Z_1)=0+Z_2$, then $(x,0)\in W$, hence $x\in Z_1$, so $x+Z_1=0+Z_1$. Thus, the kernel of $T$ is trivial.
Fourth, $T$ is surjective: if $y\in W_2$, then there exists $x\in W_1$ such that $(x,y)\in W$, and hence $T(x+Z_1) = y+Z_2$. So every element of $W_2/Z_2$ lies in the image of $T$.
Fifth and finally, $W=W_T$. If $(x,y)\in W$, then by definition we have $T(x+Z_1) = y+Z_2$, so $W\subseteq W_T$. Conversely, if $(x,y)\in W_T$, then $T(x+Z_1) = y+Z_2$, and therefore there exists $y'\in W_2$ such that $(x,y')\in W$ and $y+Z_2=y'+Z_2$. But the latter means that $y-y'\in Z_2$, hence $(0,y-y')\in W$. Thus, $(x,y')+(0,y-y') = (x,y)\in W$. Thus, $W_T\subseteq W$, giving equality.
This proves the result. $\Box$
The description now follows for the case of $V\times V$: every subspace of $V\times V$ is the graph of an isomorphism of the form $W_1/Z_1\cong W_2/Z_2$ for some subspaces $W_1,W_2,Z_1,Z_2$ of $V$ with $Z_i\leq W_i$.
Note also that $W_T=W_U$ if and only if $T=U$.

Perfect. This is just what I was looking for.
